# Poor performance with WebLogic's HttpURLConnection implementation

Tags: java, performance, http, https, weblogic12c

I have this standalone program that I ran on a server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
          URL url = new URL("http://XXXXXXXX:5310/Testing/hello.html");
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          System.out.println("HttpUrlConnection class: " + conn.getClass().getName());
          conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
          conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          conn.setDoInput(true);
          System.out.println("start: " + new java.util.Date().toString());
          System.out.println("response code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
          System.out.println("end: " + new java.util.Date().toString());
        } catch (Exception exception) {
          System.out.println("error: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
        System.exit(0);
        }

}
```

It will fetch a very simple HTML file that is deployed on WebLogic 12.2.1 that is running on the same server. The execution is very fast and it takes less than a second to get a response, as you can see from the output:

```
HttpUrlConnection class: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
start: Tue Mar 22 13:28:30 SGT 2016
response code: 200
end: Tue Mar 22 13:28:30 SGT 2016
```

Using the same codes, I put it in a JSP instead and deployed it to WebLogic on the same server:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.net.ssl.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.security.*" %>

<html>

<%
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://XXXXXXXX:5310/Testing/hello.html");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        out.print("HttpUrlConnection class: " + conn.getClass().getName() + "<br>");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        out.print("start: " + new java.util.Date().toString() + "<br>");
        out.println("response code: " + conn.getResponseCode() + "<br>");
        out.print("end: " + new java.util.Date().toString() + "<br>");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        out.println("error: " + exception.getMessage() + "<br>");
    }
%>

</html>
```

The execution is very slow, usually around 5 seconds:

```
HttpUrlConnection class: weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection
start: Tue Mar 22 13:31:22 SGT 2016
response code: 200
end: Tue Mar 22 13:31:28 SGT 2016
```

From my observations, WebLogic's implementations of HttpURLConnection and HttpsURLConnection have poor performances. See my other question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080108/slow-2-way-ssl-handshake-with-weblogic-net-http-httpsurlconnection

What is the reason for this? This is quite frustrating for me as 5 seconds is just ridiculous!

Another weird thing is that WebLogic is returning a SOAPHttpURLConnection object when I call URL.openConnection(), even though I am requesting for a plain HTML file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to using `-DUseSunHttpHandler=true` in the Weblogic and it will use a `HttpURLConnection` instead of a `SOAPHttpURLConnection`.